# How is Dru-Zod/General Zod still alive after this character died?

Tags: krypton

From the TV Show Krypton, Dru-Zod is the son of Seg-El and Lyta-Zod. In S02E05 'A better yesterday', Lyta-Zod's throat gets slit by Jax-Ur leading to Lyta's death. How is Dru-Zod still alive? Shouldn't he be wiped from existence?

Comment: Season 2 is apparently still ongoing, so it's possible this may be answered in a later episode.

Comment: @F1Krazy alright.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't know how Dru-Zod is still alive after altering his history (or even the fate of Kal-El (Superman) as we see his cape regenerate but with the Zod Crest instead of the El Crest).

However I suspect that the fact Dur-Zod is still alive is apart of a bigger issue. in Episode 4 of Season 2

> **Adam:** You're the scientist here, but I think that somehow, somewhere along the way I I think I might have effed up and And broke the damn universe.
>   **Val:** Broke it?
>   **Adam:** Yeah.
>   **Val:** What do you mean? 
>   **Adam:** Well, before I returned to Krypton I was using the Zeta-Beam and I I caught a glimpse of the future, but there was nothing. It was like I hit a wall. There was nowhere that I could go forward. It was as if, uh, time had stopped. Okay, now, what if what if everything that's happened with Brainiac and Zod, Krypton and Earth, what if everything that's changed since I gave Seg the Sunstone, what if all that rippled through time and space and has been building like a tsunami into this catastrophic universe-ending shitstorm and And what if it's all my fault? 
>   **Val:** Adam, whatever you saw, I highly doubt that you were responsible.

Source: [Krypton (2018) s02e04 Episode Script (From springfieldspringfield which i swear has the crappiest way of showing scripts)](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=krypton-2018&episode=s02e04)

According to Adam there is no future and we know this has changed since Season 1 because at the start of Season 2 Adam tell Val how Seg might be able to get out of the Phantom Zone because when Adam used his Zeta-Beam to get back to Earth in his time we found his home not only colonized by Kyptonians but also in one of Brainiac's "Jars" (what we saw at the end of Season 1) suggesting that Brainiac would get out and continue to add to his collection.

This would suggest the Future is being slowly eroded into nothing and at some point it's going to catch up to the current events in the series. Dru-Zod being alive may be a side effect of this *"catastrophic universe-ending shitstorm"* or may even be the cause being a paradox in himself if he didn't have any way to have himself be born and to go back in time to ensure causality (as we now know he wanted the Growth Codex to weaponize against Doomsday)